# Yahoo! account hacked? Virus? Legitimate incoming emails are going to trash & save folders

Tags: yahoo-mail

My Yahoo! email account was working fine until I noticed an email from a co-worker bypassed my inbox all together and ended up in my trash file. I checked all my filters and blocked addresses and did not find anything that could be causing the problem.

I put up with the inconvenience and just kept checking my trash folder for her emails. It was only her emails that were by passing my inbox. This has been going on for a couple of months.

My account was hacked about a week ago and I changed the password of my account.

Now I have several other emails from clients which have also bypassed my inbox. These emails are ending up in my trash folder and my SAVE folder.

What do I do?

Comment: had the same problem today.  Why on earth do yahoo have such a feature it's crazy.  Fingers crossed stopped a withdrawal of €8,000 from my trading account.

Answer (score 2):

Helped a friend figure this out yesterday.

In Yahoo! Mail, click the little Gear symbol (top right) and select *Settings*.  Then select *Filters*.  Look carefully...is there a filter named simply `.`    (just a period)?  That's your problem.  It is telling Yahoo to send all mail addressed to you to the Trash.  Remove it and you should be all good.